# Populating rows into a Dataset that I created?

Tags: c#

I created a DataSet in C# called InvoiceDS which is under a root folder of the application called Datasets. I need to use the DataSet to populate rows in a Crystal Report. The issue I am battling with is that my function needs to return a populated DataSet and not just DataTable

My Current Code:

```
public static Datasets.InvoiceDS.tbl_InvoiceDataTable GetData()
    {
        Datasets.InvoiceDS.tbl_InvoiceDataTable dtc = new Datasets.InvoiceDS.tbl_InvoiceDataTable();
        Datasets.InvoiceDS.tbl_InvoiceRow dtr = dtc.Newtbl_InvoiceRow();

        dtr["Code"] = "";
        dtr["Description"] = "";
        dtr["Quantity"] = "";
        dtr["Unit"] = "";
        dtr["UnitPrice"] = "";
        dtr["Tax"] = "";
        dtr["NettPrice"] = "";

        dtc.Rows.Add(dtr);

        return dtc;
    }
```

I have tried doing DataSet ds = DataSets.InvoiceDS but I have hit a brick wall

Comment: What are these types? Did you roll your own DataSet/DataTable/DataRow classes..? Also, can't you just declare a DataSet, add your table to it, change the return type of your method, and return the DataSet?

Comment: I have created by own DataSet yes that has its own fields by adding a DataSet item to the Project